Trouble with an ArrayFormula formula on Google Sheets
I'm currently using a formula that displays exactly what I want but I want this formula to work all the way down the column which is why I tried to use ArrayFormula but it doesn't work with Query.
The formula:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;QUERY(DATA!$A$2:$FN;"SELECT FN WHERE K matches '"&$D2&"'"))

What I tried with ArrayFormula:
=Arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;QUERY(DATA!$A$2:$FN;"SELECT FN WHERE K matches '"&$D2&"'")))

Both formulas display the same result on the first cell only. How can I modify my formula to work on the entire column?
Sheet sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2wqJwoCdxUuXDZ4_cC7sHHb5YybMqA42HfikN0Nijk/edit

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2wqJwoCdxUuXDZ4_cC7sHHb5YybMqA42HfikN0Nijk/edit


You may try this in Cell_M2:
=map(D2:D;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;textjoin(char(10);1;ifna(filter(DATA!FN:FN;DATA!K:K=Σ))))))



Incredible stuff, thank you so much, I won't have to duplicate my formula on every cell and make everything lag!
